After installing Lombok the Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library (Windows 10)
I have installed Lombok with
java -jar lombok.jar

However now I can't run eclipse as "the Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library (Windows)". What to do and how to install it properly?
After installation lombok.jar appeared in eclipse folder.
Attaching the eclipse.ini
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.800.v20240513-1750.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\�������\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.1000.v20240507-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\�������\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.32.0.20240606-1231
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-22/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclientjava
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=21
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Declipse.e4.inject.javax.warning=false
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Djava.security.manager=allow
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-oomph/oomph/master/setups/
-javaagent:C:\Users\Альбина\eclipse\jee-2024-06\eclipse\lombok.jar


I tried to install Lombok several times and eclipse crashed exactly after that.

That part of the output renders your username correctly and part of it does not makes it look like this might be an issue with the encoding on your machine and that path. Try placing Eclipse outside of your home directory, while also keeping it out of Program Files. Unless you want to first try fixing the paths in the eclipse.ini file.

@nitind i've reinstalled eclipse into a newly created folder "C:\My Programs\Eclipse" so that there weren't any cyrillic symbols and tried to install Lombok not with "java -jar lombok.jar" but through "Help->Install New Software" and "https://projectlombok.org/p2", it helped, now there's no such error anymore, it launches. Don't know what helped exactly but thnx for the comment!

As user nitind said i've reinstalled eclipse into a newly created folder "C:\My Programs\Eclipse" so that there weren't any cyrillic symbols and I also tried to install Lombok not with "java -jar lombok.jar" but through "Help->Install New Software" and "projectlombok.org/p2", it helped, now there's no such error anymore, it finally launches. Don't know what helped exactly, but it worked out!

